# android - get translate animation completion percentage

Tags: android, animation

I have an animation defined in xml, with repeat set to infinity, and a duration set to half a second. As the animation goes along, I'd like to able to know where it's at. That is, if it's been translated 25%, 40%, 90%, etc. Is there a way to get a simple float that represents this as a percent of time?

Comment: i've found a solution, but it's not the simple function call i was looking for. i basically just take the remainder from AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis() and .getDuration() and then return that number divided by the .getDuration(). i still feel like there should be a simpler approach.